# passing arguments through fminsearch to ode45

Tags: matlab

I need to solve a system of seven diff. equations and find the optimal set of coefficients (eight values for **k** and seven for **y0**) via fminsearching the minimal difference with respect to the experimental values.

```
function dY = KIN241(t,y,k)
%
% version 2: direct formation of intermediates of the type {L}2M from MR3 and L (ligand)
% MR3  +  2L  --> {L}2M
% simultaneous formation of 4 intermediates A, B, C and D in four parallel reactions, 
% followed by 4 reactions to afford only one product P
%
%   dL/dt = -2*k_tot*MR3*(L)^2, where k_tot = k_LA + k_LB + k_LC + k_LD
%   dMR3/dt = -k_tot*MR3*(L)^2
%   with :
%   Variables: x(1) =  L, x(2) = MR3
%   Parameters: B(1) = k_LA, B(2) = k_LB, B(3) = k_LC, B(4) = k_LD 
%
%   dP/dt = k_AP*A + k_BP*B + k_CP*C + k_DP*D
%   dA/dt = 2*k_LA*MR3*(L)^2 - k_AP*A
%   dB/dt = 2*k_LB*MR3*(L)^2 - k_BP*B
%   dC/dt = 2*k_LC*MR3*(L)^2 - k_CP*C
%   dD/dt = 2*k_LA*MR3*(L)^2 - k_DP*D
%
%   with :
%   Variables: y(3) =  P, y(4) = A, y(5) = B, y(6) = C, y(7) = D
%   Parameters: B(5) = k_AP, B(6) = k_BP, B(7) = k_CP, B(8) = k_DP 
%   dL = dY(1); 
%   dMR3 = dY(2); 
%   dP = dY(3); 
%   dA = dY(4); 
%   dB = dY(5); 
%   dC = dY(6); 
%   dD = dY(7);
%y = indata;
%B = rand(1,8);
%disp(B);
k_LA = k(1);
k_LB = k(2);
k_LC = k(3);
k_LD = k(4);
k_AP = k(5);
k_BP = k(6);
k_CP = k(7);
k_DP = k(8);
%
        dY(1) = -2.*(k_LA + k_LB + k_LC + k_LD).*y(2).*(y(1))^2; 
        dY(2) = -(k_LA + k_LB + k_LC + k_LD).*y(2).*(y(1))^2;
        dY(3) = k_AP.*y(4) + k_BP.*y(5) + k_CP.*y(6) + k_DP.*y(7);
        dY(4) = 2.*k_LA.*y(2).*(y(1))^2 - k_AP.*y(4);
        dY(5) = 2.*k_LB.*y(2).*(y(1))^2 - k_BP.*y(5);
        dY(6) = 2.*k_LC.*y(2).*(y(1))^2 - k_CP.*y(6);
        dY(7) = 2.*k_LD.*y(2).*(y(1))^2 - k_DP.*y(7);
 dY = [dY(1); dY(2); dY(3); dY(4); dY(5); dY(6); dY(7)];
```

The function, which calls ode is the following:

```
function SSE = SSE_minimization(tspan_inp,val_exp,par)
         k_inp = par{1};
         y0_inp = par{2};
         f = @(Tt,Ty) KIN241(Tt,Ty,k_inp);  %function to call ode45
         %size_limit = length(k_inp);
         %options = odeset('NonNegative',1:size_limit,'RelTol',1e-8,'AbsTol',[1e-8   1e-8     1e-8 1e-8 1e-8 1e-8 1e-8]);
         [ts,val_theo] = ode45(f, tspan_inp, y0_inp);  %Cexp is the state variable     predicted by the model
         err = val_exp - val_theo;
         SSE = sum(sum(err.^2));   %sum squared-error
```

The experimetal data is there:

Time_M =

```
       0
      60
     381
     702
    1023
    1344
    1665
    1986
    2307
    2628
    2949
    3270
    3591
    3912
    4233
    4554
    4875
    5196
    5517
    5838
    6159
    6480
    6801
    7122
    7443
    7764
    8085
```

and

Concentration_M =

```
0.0385    0.0224    0.0385    0.0385    0.0385    0.0385    0.0064
0.0384    0.0343    0.0381    0.0351    0.0359    0.0262    0.0301
0.0374    0.0377    0.0251    0.0207    0.0377    0.0348    0.0369
0.0364    0.0379    0.0184    0.0264    0.0376    0.0366    0.0373
0.0358    0.0380    0.0163    0.0291    0.0375    0.0371    0.0375
0.0353    0.0380    0.0162    0.0300    0.0374    0.0373    0.0376
0.0348    0.0381    0.0166    0.0305    0.0374    0.0374    0.0376
0.0344    0.0381    0.0170    0.0312    0.0373    0.0374    0.0377
0.0339    0.0381    0.0177    0.0312    0.0372    0.0376    0.0378
0.0336    0.0382    0.0184    0.0317    0.0372    0.0375    0.0378
0.0331    0.0382    0.0190    0.0317    0.0372    0.0376    0.0379
0.0327    0.0382    0.0194    0.0319    0.0372    0.0376    0.0379
0.0324    0.0382    0.0201    0.0322    0.0372    0.0376    0.0379
0.0320    0.0382    0.0206    0.0324    0.0371    0.0377    0.0379
0.0317    0.0382    0.0212    0.0327    0.0371    0.0376    0.0380
0.0313    0.0382    0.0217    0.0328    0.0371    0.0377    0.0380
0.0309    0.0382    0.0222    0.0329    0.0371    0.0377    0.0380
0.0307    0.0382    0.0228    0.0333    0.0371    0.0377    0.0380
0.0304    0.0383    0.0233    0.0335    0.0371    0.0377    0.0381
0.0301    0.0383    0.0237    0.0337    0.0371    0.0377    0.0381
0.0299    0.0383    0.0242    0.0339    0.0371    0.0378    0.0381
0.0296    0.0383    0.0248    0.0341    0.0371    0.0378    0.0381
0.0291    0.0383    0.0250    0.0336    0.0370    0.0378    0.0381
0.0288    0.0383    0.0255    0.0339    0.0370    0.0382    0.0381
0.0285    0.0383    0.0258    0.0340    0.0370    0.0378    0.0382
0.0283    0.0383    0.0262    0.0341    0.0370    0.0378    0.0382
0.0283    0.0383    0.0268    0.0346    0.0370    0.0379    0.0381
```

When I call from the main code:

```
    y0 = (rand(1,7))';
    k0 = (rand(1,8))';
    par0{1} = k0; par0{2} = y0;
[solution, fval, exitflag, output] = fminsearch(@(par) SSE_minimization(tspan,Concentration_M,par0),y0);
        k_opt = solution(1);
        y0 = solution(2);
```

after one cycle I get the following error:

```
 Attempted to access k(2); index out of bounds because numel(k)=1.

Error in KIN241 (line 34)
k_LB = k(2);
```

Actually, the code finds only one value for k_opt instead of eight, and only one for y0 instead of seven...

Could you please help me to set up / correct the code in order to optimize both k and y0 parameters for this system of equations.

Thanks much in advance !